# Can I run multiprocess of subprocesses in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing

I want to process data faster with the JAVA base machine learning app: MOA, so I split my data into many small batches, so the `input =[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],...]`. for each input I want to process them parallel. Can I use multiprocess's `Pool` for that?

```py
def batch_process(input):
    ...some pandas processing
    // p = Pool(1000)
    // map to subprocess, can I do that??
    subprocess.run(...)
...
```

Comment: check library threading or _thread

Answer (score 1):

```
import threading
def batch_process(input):
    ...some pandas processing
    // p = Pool(1000)
    // map to subprocess, can I do that??    
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=subprocess, args=(10,))
    # starting thread 1
     t1.start()
     ...
```